# Sanitize mysql injection string with preg_match

Tags: php, mysql, sanitization

I want to sanitize data against mysql injection.
So I need to write a pattern to recognize and remove 4 main mysql SELECT, Replace, DELETE , UPDATE.

I want to use this general rule for array_map

```
$_POST = array_map('stz',$_POST);
```

However I stuck in to write that pattern to against happens like this
"  ' AND 1=1; SELECT * FROM test_table "

Comment: What's wrong with using Prepared Statements?  https://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: what's supposed to be in the $_POST ?

Comment: Or if you're using an API without prepared statements, what's wrong with its escape function?

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong approach. Consult [this SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php?rq=1) and [this reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1u9jl5/how_do_you_handle_sanitizing_get_and_post/).

Comment: Why inventing the wheel? use $stz = mysql_real_escape($_POST['stz']);

Comment: @talsibony the proper function is `mysqli_escape_string()`

Comment: @rybo111 You are right (depricated in newer versions of PHP)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can do it. Here are a few:

#### Create a variable each time

```
$clean_forename = mysqli_escape_string($db, $_POST["forename"]);
```

#### Create a clean array

```
$clean = array();
$clean["forename"] = mysqli_escape_string($db, $_POST["forename"]);
```

#### Sanitize in the SQL query

```
$sql_query = "UPDATE table SET forename='".mysqli_escape_string($db, $_POST["forename"])."'";
```

#### Use a foreach

```
$set = array();
$keys = array('forename', 'surname', 'email');
foreach($keys as $val) {
  $safe_value = mysqli_escape_string($db, $_POST[$val]);
  array_push($set, "$val='$safe_value'");
}
$set_query = implode(',', $set);
$sql_query = "UPDATE table SET $set_query";
```

Comment: what if you want to keep the post with the injection for farther use?

Comment: -1. NEVER modify superglobals.

Answer (score -3):

Don't use regex.
there is dedicated function for cleaning if you wish to clean all your post array
you can use simple foreach:

```
<?php
    $cleanpostArr = array();
    foreach($_POST as $postkey => $postvalue){
      $cleanpostArr[mysqli_escape_string($db,$postkey)] = mysqli_escape_string($db,$postvalue);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape` is deprecated.

Comment: Now you've edited: `mysqli_escape_string` requires the database connection.

Comment: Yes, edited the point is why using regex when you have dedicated function.

Comment: what is wrong with this answer?, added escape to the key because it can also include sql injection.